# gnuplot: plotting contour without labels works, with labels no

Tags: label, gnuplot, contour

i am trying to plot a contour from a gridded data file called 'sample'. This script works fine for me:

```
set xrange[1:1e2]; set yrange[1:1e2]; set log;
set view map; unset surface
set style textbox opaque margins  0.5,  0.5 noborder
set contour base
set cntrlabel  format '%5.3g' font ',7'
set cntrparam levels discrete 1e40,1e42,1e44
splot 'sample' u ($1*1e27):($2*1e18):3 wl
```

it plots a 2D plot with contour lines. All fine.
If i only dare to continue the plotting line with

```
'' u ($1*1e27):($2*1e18):3 with labels boxed notitle
```

to add labels to the contour lines, it takes around 15 minutes to produce a blank plot. Using gnuplot examples on sourceforge, it works. 
Have you ever experienced something similar?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: That plots one label for every data point. How many points do you have?

Comment: i have around 1000 data points, but actually i didnt know that it plots one label for every data plot. I am trying to add a label to every contour line, no more.

Comment: dear @Christoph, i considered your suggestion and found the missing part. now i am able to put labels as i prefer, but it anyway takes 15 minutes to produce the plot, dont know why. Thank you for suggestions

Comment: Without having a _full_ example and more information (OS, gnuplot version), it is quite useless to speculate about such errors.